# Formik Yup - Check if the fields have duplicated values

Tags: reactjs, react-native, formik, yup

I have a form in my React Native application, which was built using Formik and Yup.

Here’s the structure:
[image]

[image]

If one of the answerOptions text inputs contains the same values as in the others, the duplicated fields should be highlighted in red. Both 2, 3, 4 values can be duplicated and should be highlighted in red.

What could be the solution?

Thanks in advance!